# libxls: xls_open() crashs because the pathname of the file

Tags: c, excel, xls

I'm using libxls library to read .xls files in C language.
But, it crashs occasionally with the same Excel file when i change the path of the file.

Does anyone have an idea how to fixe this problem?

Comment: How can it be the same file with a different path?

Comment: I change the path of my Excel file then, a copy this file into the new directory. Then, i call xls_open() to open it with the new path.